# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'User_Economy'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, object, types

I spend most time for that question, but dont have a answer

Error:
`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'User_Economy'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User_Economy'.`

```
    interface User_Economy {
        rep: number
        money: number
        level: number
        xp: number
        box: number[]
    }
    interface User_Interface{
        Economy: User_Economy
    }
    data = await this.client.db.insert_one<User_Interface>('users', User_basic(member.id, message.guild.id));
    const type: keyof {[key: string]: User_Economy} = ['level', 'money', 'rep', 'xp'].find(x => {
                return typed.toLowerCase() === x ? x : null
            })
    data.Economy[type] += Math.floor(parseInt(amount));
```

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the `const type` that you have defined now is `string`.
As the error suggests, the `User_Economy` interface has no index signature with a parameter of type 'string', i.e. something like:

```
interface User_Economy {
  [key: string]: unknown;
}
```

The `const type` that you are looking to use in the last line, instead of a `keyof {[key: string]: User_Economy}` (equivalent to `string`), should be a `keyof User_Economy`, i.e. a singular predefined key of `User_Economy`, in order to reference a key of `User_Economy` as it is currently defined.

There are other issues with the supplied code, such as the `User_Economy.box` property not being assignable by the `+=` operator. You would want to use the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) utility type to exclude it from the results. Another issue is that the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method can return `undefined` and that must be accounted for before assigning `data.Economy[type]`.

As an example, below is some code that always adds `1` to `data.Economy.level`, resulting in its value being set to `2`:

```
interface User_Economy {
  rep: number;
  money: number;
  level: number;
  xp: number;
  box: number[];
}
interface User_Interface{
  Economy: User_Economy;
}
type KUEExcludingBox = Exclude<keyof User_Economy, 'box'>;

const data: User_Interface = {
  Economy: {
    rep: 1,
    money: 1,
    level: 1,
    xp: 1,
    box: [],
  },
};

const key: KUEExcludingBox | undefined = (['level', 'money', 'rep', 'xp'] as KUEExcludingBox[])
  .find(x => 'level' === x);
if (key !== undefined) {
  data.Economy[key] += Math.floor(parseInt('1'));
}

console.log(data);
```

View it on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

###### Asides

- You should avoid using keywords like `type` as variable names.
- The [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) callback should generally return a boolean value, though it also accepts truthy/falsey values. The first element that the callback returns truthy for will be the element returned by `find()`. There is no reason in this case for the extra processing of the `typed.toLowerCase() === x ? x : null`. Just use `typed.toLowerCase() === x`.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know about Exclude )))